# Boost Asio async_wait handler

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The boost asio `deadline_timer` `async_wait` function is taking handler of the form :

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
```

How could I define a handler which takes in `const boost::system::error_code& error` and also an argument of type `int` ?

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io_service);

t.async_wait(handler); //I need the async_wait to take in handler which accepts argument boost::system::error_code& error and an int 

void handler(int, const boost::system::error_code& error )//extra int argument
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html) to provide a value for the first argument :

```
t.async_wait(boost::bind(handler, 0, _1));
```

Here, the handler will be called with a 0 as its first argument and the `error_code` will simply be forwarded as a second argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just curious, what does the symbol _1 mean in this context and where could I use it else where?

Comment: @Steveng: It's a placeholder that only has a meaning in the context of a `boost::bind` which refers to the first argument passed to the functor returned by this `bind`. The number of arguments taken by the functor returned by `bind` is the maximum ordinal of the placeholders specified : here, the result of `bind` is a functor that expects a single argument which is forwarded as the second argument of `handler`.

Comment: @Steveng: actually the documentation says it much better that I do "_1 is a placeholder argument that means "substitute with the first input argument."